# How send SMS command over GPRS to teltonika devices fmbXXX

Tags: node.js, gprs, teltonika

I want to send SMS command over GPRS to teltonika devices `fmbXXX` , I got response when I send the command `getio` but other commands didn't work

Here is the script just for test

```
const net = require("net");
const Parser = require("teltonika-parser");
const server = net.createServer((socket) => {
  console.log("Client connected:", socket.remoteAddress, socket.remotePort);
  socket.on("data", async (data) => {
    let parser = new Parser(data);
    if (parser.isImei) {
//  socket.write(Buffer.from('000000000000000D0C010500000005676574696F01000000CB', 'hex'));  //getio  it work
    socket.write( Buffer.from(  "000000000000000f0C010500000007676574696e666f0100004312","hex")); //getinfo no response
    } else {
      console.log(parser);
      console.log("" + parser._codecReader.ByteBuffer + "");
    }
  });
  socket.on("close", () => {
    console.log("Client disconnected");
  });
  socket.on("error", (error) => {   
     console.error("Socket error:", error);
  });
});
server.listen(4043, "192.168.1.21", () => {
  console.log("TCP server listening ");
});
```

The code above works in `getio` command but the other command as `getinfo` or others not working
part of the compilation unit:

Answer (score 2):

not all SMS commands are included in Teltonika' Codec12. Also not all commands are the same over different families of Teltonika devices (*36, FM*64*, FMB***).

Check this: https://wiki.teltonika-gps.com/view/Codec#Codec_12